# Mount options for increased security

Tags: linux, mount, security, fstab

I am aiming to increasing security of our Linux server  with `nodev`, `nosuid` and `noexec` mount options. Please find the attached image about showing my `fstab` file.

[image]

My question is about `/boot` written in the UUID line. While it seems to be `/tmp` in order to set `nodev`, `nosuid` and `noexec` options. In case of cltering `/boot` to `/tmp`, where else do I need to change? Could I alter `/boot` to `/tmp`? What would the effects of that be?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Comment: Please proof read and correct. I see that you have a question about the `/boot` line but have no idea what.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `/boot` filesystem to `/tmp` in `/etc/fstab`, then after your next reboot, your kernel and initramfs files will be in `/tmp` and might get removed if your system has an automatic process to clean up `/tmp` either at boot or periodically at some intervals. Then, once the cleanup process has removed your kernel and initramfs files from your /boot-as-/tmp filesystem, your system would fail to boot again.

To properly repurpose your current `/boot` filesystem as `/tmp`, you would have to do several things first:

- ensure that your bootloader version is capable of reading the kernel and initramfs files from a LVM logical volume
- mount the `/boot` filesystem to a temporary location like `/mnt`, then copy or move the kernel and initramfs files from `/mnt` (which used to be `/boot`) to a new `/boot` directory that will now be just a regular directory on the root filesystem
- reinstall your bootloader, and make sure it's actually configured to read the kernel and initramfs files from your LVM-based root filesystem instead of a separate filesystem that used to be `/boot`
- boot the system once to ensure you haven't made mistakes, before actually reusing the old `/boot` filesystem as `/tmp`

All this is a lot of detailed work with a risk of making your system unbootable if you get it wrong. **I would suggest not repurposing your `/boot` as `/tmp` unless you don't have any alternative.**

Instead, if you want a separate `/tmp` filesystem, you could use a RAM-based `tmpfs` for the purpose. Basically, just add a new line like this to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs  /tmp tmpfs defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 0 0
```

And after you reboot the system, you now should have a RAM-based `/tmp` filesystem with the security options in effect.

Or alternatively, if you want a `/tmp` that can preserve its contents over a reboot, and you have unallocated space in your `vg_smpp` volume group, you could easily create a new LVM logical volume for `/tmp`.

- First, use the `vgs` command to see if the `vg_smpp` volume group has enough unallocated space for your purpose: if the `VFree` column is not zero, there is unallocated space available in the volume group.
- If there is unallocated space, you can use `lvcreate -L <desired size> -n lv_tmp vg_smpp` to create a new logical volume `/dev/mapper/vg_smpp-lv_tmp`. Just replace `<desired size>` with the size you want for your new `/tmp` filesystem.
- Once the logical volume has been created, you'll need to make a filesystem on it: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg_smpp-lv_tmp`.
- Then, you can add a line in `/etc/fstab` for it:

  /dev/mapper/vg_smpp-lv_tmp /tmp ext4 defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec 1 2
- Now you can mount it on top of your existing `/tmp` directory: `mount /tmp`. The next step after this is to set up appropriate permissions for the newly-mounted /tmp filesystem: `chmod 1777 /tmp`, or `drwxrwxrwt`. In other words, anyone can use the `/tmp` filesystem, but there is an additional restriction that only the owner of a file or sub-directory can delete it. This is the standard and expected set of permissions for the `/tmp` directory.
- Any existing programs with active temporary files might be a bit confused about this replacement, so it would be a good idea to reboot at this point.